# Form in jQuery UI Dialog Cached.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a C/C++ programmer and new to javascript. The following code is giving me grief and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. I've searched and can't find where others have had the same problem.

I've taken my project and cut out my problem code to try and understand and fix it. The short version is when I click my "Enter data" image on an HTML page, it creates a dialog box with a form and table of inputs (with default data) and I enter/change some data. When I click the dialog box save button, it goes through JSON.stringify($('#form').jsonify()) to collect the form data and brings up an alert box showing the data that I entered. This part works fine.

If I click the "Enter data" image again, the dialog box comes up and I enter/change new data. When I click the dialog box save button, it brings up an alert box showing the previous data that I saved (in this case showed in the alert box).

No matter how many times I try it, it always returns the data form the very first entry and never any of the new(er) data.

What am I doing wrong?

Some references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/test.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/jquery/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My HTML code

```
<div>
<img id="additem"
        Title="Add Item"
        onclick="addstuff(this)"
        OnMouseOver="this.style.cursor='pointer';"
        OnMouseOut="this.style.cursor='default';"
        src="~/images/Sign_Add_Icon_32.png" />
</div>
```

My test.js file.

```
$.fn.jsonify = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        stringify: false
    }, options);
    var json = {};
    $.each(this.serializeArray(), function () {
        if (json[this.name]) {
            if (!json[this.name].push)
                json[this.name] = [json[this.name]];
            json[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else
            json[this.name] = this.value || '';
    });
    if (settings.stringify)
        return JSON.stringify(json);
    else
        return json;
}

function addstuff(obj) {
    var strHtml = "";
    var strHtml = "<div class=\"container\" id=\"addphonedlg\" title=\"Add Phone\" overflow:\"auto\">"
                     + "<p>Please enter the following information.</p>"
                     + "<form id=\"form\"><table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">"

                     + "<tr><td align=\"right\"><label for=\"name\">" + "Data 1" + ":</label></td>"
                     + "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"" + "data1" + "\" style=\"border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; align=right;\" VALUE=\"" + "Data 1 data" + "\" />" + "</td></tr>"
                     + "<tr><td align=\"right\"><label for=\"name\">" + "Data 2" + ":</label></td>"
                     + "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"" + "data2" + "\" style=\"border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; align=right;\" VALUE=\"" + "Data 2 data" + "\" />" + "</td></tr>"
                     + "<tr><td align=\"right\"><label for=\"name\">" + "Data 3" + ":</label></td>"
                     + "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"" + "data3" + "\" style=\"border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; align=right;\" VALUE=\"" + "Data 3 data" + "\" />" + "</td></tr>"

                     + "</table></form>"
                     + "</div>";

    $(strHtml).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                alert("Add information " + JSON.stringify($('#form').jsonify()));
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button:contains('Cancel')").focus();
        }
    }).dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: This is gonna sound really condescending, but is there any way you could put a working example showcasing your problem on http://jsfiddle.net/? Your problem seems simple enough, but it's really annoying to try and solve these kinds of things if you can't play around with them.

Comment: I agree with @Reck. A jsfiddle will help us help you quicker.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I've only recently learned of jsfiddle

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the javascript 'addstuff' to even execute on the click in jsfiddle.

Comment: try clearing strHtml above where you assign the element string to it. ie, var strHtml = ""; strHtml = "<div class .... etc...

Comment: I just tried that and updated my posted code to reflect it. No dice. Same thing

Comment: first thing, why do you have a table in a form?

Comment: I'm using the table to aide in formatting the output. i.e help line things up

Comment: ok, you don't really need that but that's not the problem. looking into it.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm still trying to jsfiddle going. For what ever reason, I even get an alert from the js when I click the image in jsfiddle. Oooh at the side problems. hahaha

Comment: Here's the fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/lgavitt/ug7LL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a known problem of forms in ui dialogs being cached. But you need to remove the form `onClose` of the `dialog`.
I added close event function to your code. You should be fine now.

```
    $(strHtml).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        close: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#form').remove(); // this where the problem is
        },
        buttons: {
            Save: function () {
                alert("Add information " + JSON.stringify($('#form1').jsonify()));
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button:contains('Cancel')").focus();
        }
    }).dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: Man. Many thanks. That solved my problem. I can't thank you enough for applying the effort to research, find, and explain the problem.